# Why does super.addAll calls the overridden add method

Tags: java

I have a class myHashSet which extends HashSet class. myHashSet overrides add() and addAll() methods of HashSet. So I have the following code snippet:

```
class MyHashSet<E> extends HashSet<E> {

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e){
       return super.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection ? extends E> c){
       return super.addAll(c);
    }
}
```

I know that, addAll method is implemented over add(), meaning it uses add() method. So, if I call MyHashSet's addAll(), it should invoke HashSet's addAll(), which in turn should invoke HashSet's add().. But why is it calling MyHashSet's add(), when I call MyHashSet's addAll()?

I am confused here, sorry if the question is very silly.

Comment: That's not how it works. Since `add()` is called on `this` and `this` is a `MyHashSet`, then the most specific version of the method is called.

Comment: @DekDekku But I use super.addAll() and super.add() which must invoke the super class's method right? There is no **this** here.

Comment: You use `super.addAll()` and `super.addAll()` uses `this.add()` (which in turns delegates to `super.add()` so you could just as well remove it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way polymorphism is working.

If you have class hierarchy A and B where B extends A and you have overridden method `foo()` when you call it the method of subclass will be executed. The syntax `super.foo()`  allows calling super class's version of method. But if then the super class's method calls `bar()` it will call the version written in subclass. Think about it: this allows inheritance to work because you can override methods of super class in sublass and change the functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You have overridden `add()`. That means whenever `add()` is called on an instance of `MyHashSet`, your overridden method is called. It doesn't matter where the call site is: even if it's inside a method of the super type, your overridden method will be called. Why would you expect it to work otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

The call sequence is as follows:

1. You call `MyHashSet::addAll()`
2. `MyHashSet::addAll()` calls `HashSet::addAll()` using `super->addAll()`
3. `HashSet::addAll()` calls `MyHashSet::add()` using `this->add()`
4. `MyHashSet::add()` calls `HashSet::add()` using `super->add()`

In steps 1 and 3 the calls are `virtual`, so they invoke the latest implementations.

Comment: I think `virtual` is rather a C++ concept and mentioning it here might confuse beginners in Java.

Answer (score 0):

`MyHashSet's addAll()` used `MyHashSet's add()` method inside.you overridden that method So obviously it will come there.