# HashSet addAll method modifies class internal field

Tags: java, hashset

I have a class which extends a parametrized version of HashSet. This class has an internal field `currentSize` which keeps track of how many elements have been added so far. The child class overrides the base class' `add` and `addAll` methods so the `currentSize` increases accordingly. My problem is that inside `addAll`, the size of the set is added two times to the `currentSize` counter, not once. Below is my class' code:

```
public class InheritHashSet extends HashSet<Integer> {
    private int currentSize = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean add(Integer e) {
        currentSize++;
        super.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Integer> e) {
        currentSize += e.size();
        super.addAll(e);
    }

    public int getCurrentSize() {
        return currentSize;
    }
}
```

The `add` method seems to be working fine, since after adding three elements, `currentSize` is 3, but the following will add 6 to the `currentSize` instead of 3:

```
InheritHashSet ihs = new InheritHashSet();
Collection<Integer> c = new LinkedList<Integer>();
c.add(new Integer(0));
c.add(new Integer(1));
c.add(new Integer(2));
ihs.addAll(c);
System.out.println(ihs.getCurrentSize()); // prints 6 instead of 3
```

It looks like the call to `super.addAll(e)` also modifies the `currentSize` (this does not seem to make any sense at all).

Comment: What does `super.addAll(e);` do?

Comment: That's exactly why you should not extend HashSet, but instead *use* HashSet. Note that currentSize is very badly named. It's not the size at all. And if it were, it would be useless since HashSet already has a size.

Comment: @JBNizet I know that the size can be determined using HashSet's `size()` method, I was just wondering why does not this method of counting the number of elements in the set yield the correct answer.

Comment: look at the source for `super.addAll`. It probably calls `add` internally. That's why you get double-counting. If you extend an existing implementation you have to look at how that implementation works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476716/why-does-super-addall-calls-the-overridden-add-method

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for the link, it looks like I missed that at first.

Comment: There is no need to write `new Integer(…)` here. You can simply use `c.add(0);`, `c.add(1);`, and `c.add(2);`. But you should also be aware what will happen, if you use `c.add(0); c.add(0); c.add(0);`, i.e. that “`currentSize`” is not a size at all. It’s only counting the number of method invocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addAll()` method of the `InheritHashSet` class first set currentSize = 3, with `currentSize += e.size();` instruction. Then `super.addAll(e);` calls `add(e)` method three times. For dynamic binding the `public boolean add(Integer e)` of class `InheritHashSet` is invoked first and then `currentSize` is then incremented to 6.

for this reason you should implement `addAll` method in this way:

```
@Override
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Integer> e) {
    return super.addAll(e);
}
```

Comment: Until HashSet decides to implement addAll() by not calling add() anymore, but by delegating to a new private doAdd() method, which will then break the subclass and lead to 0 instead of 3. You should just not extend HashSet.

Comment: I'm totally agree, you're right to point this out, but we don't know what is the really intent of the OP code. May be he wrote this code only for a simple test or for study. He asked only why there was that weird behaviour, that it was not so immediate to realize.

Comment: Am I overlooking something here, or is this implementation useless? It's just calling the `super` method, and not changing visibility, so what's the point of this? And of course, JB Nizet is right. It's difficult. The "cleanest" or "safest" solution would probably be a `MySpecialSet extends AbstractSet implements Set` that implements its `size`,`iterator` and `add` methods using the desired Set (`HashSet` in this case), and does the counting solely in `add`. But I'd bet that there are **far** more elegant solutions for what the asker actually wants to achieve...

Comment: I simply removed the `currentSize` increment from the addAll implementation because I noticed that it was an error. You don't know if that method does something else and the OP simplified it because he wanted to focus on the `currentSize` problem (and in order to create a minimal working example).

Answer (score 2):

It's almost never a good idea to extend an existing collection class, specifically when you are trying to enforce a new contract.

I would recommend you redesign your class to have a HashSet field rather than extend HashSet.

Read [Effective Java by Joshua Bloch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) Item 16: Favor Composition over Inheritance.

Comment: @Sotirios yeah you were right to edit that. I would have removed that line soon anyway